# Change existing plot lines according to colormap

Tags: matlab, graphics, formatting, matlab-figure

I have a plot with a few lines in Matlab and I want to control the line colors post-hoc:

```
figure; hold on;
for ind=1:4
  plot(rand(1,10))
end
```

I know I can use

```
set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',summer(4))
```

before plotting, to change the plot line colors, but (how) can I achieve the same thing after looking at the plot? Possibly try-out a few different colorschemata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each plot by default takes its color from the property `'ColorOrder'` of their axis, which in turn is taken by default from the `'DefaultAxesColorOrder'` of the [`groot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/groot.html) object.

Once the plots have been created, you need to modify their colors individually; changing the above mentioned properties will not affect them:

```
g = findobj(gca, 'Type', 'line'); % children of current axis that are lines
c = summer(numel(g)); % desired color scheme, with that many colors
for k = 1:numel(g)
    set(g(k), 'color', c(k,:));
end
```